# how to disable multiple clicks on menu option in android

Tags: android, menu, onclick

How do you disable multiple clicks on a menu option, before the first click is processed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can set the visibility or enable/disable the item by code.

```
MenuItem item = menu.findItem(R.id.your_item);
item.setVisible(true);
item.setEnabled(false);
```

Of course you have to check somewhere whether to enable oder disable the icon.

Answer (score 2):

Psuedo/Android answer:

```
 private boolean clicked = false;

 @Override
 public onClick(View v){
   if(!clicked){
       clicked = true;


       // do your processing - one click only


       super.onClick();
   }
 }
```

*EDIT*

or even better after the first click you can call `yourView.setOnClickListener(null);` to remove the onClick

Answer (score 1):

I know that this is an old question but I want to share a reactive approach.

Fragment/Activity
onOptionsItemSelected:

```
    if (item.getItemId() == yourId) {
      viewModel.showTopUp()
      return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
```

In the ViewModel create a PublishSubject and throttle the requests to prevent multiple clicks:

```
private PublishSubject<Context> topUpClicks = PublishSubject.create();

public void showTopUp(Context context) {
    topUpClicks.onNext(context);
}

private void handleTopUpClicks() {
    disposables.add(topUpClicks.throttleFirst(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .doOnNext(transactionViewNavigator::openTopUp)
        .subscribe());
}
```